# How can I use python to add a column to a csv file with a keyword from the previous column?

Tags: python, regex, csv

Apologies if I didn't phrase my question correctly. I currently have a csv file with 2 columns of data. I want to add a third column with a keyword (from a word bank I have) only if that keyword is found in the second column. If there are no words from the word bank in the second column, then i just want the row written as is. In the example below, the third column only contains words "green" and "red" because those words are in the word bank and in the second column of the file:

```
wordbank = ["blue", "red", "green"]

apple  | "The color is green" |  green

orange | "The color is orange" | 

berry  | "Yes, red is the color"   | red
```

I thought about using regex but wasn't sure how to go about it. My code currently looks like this, but I'm new to python and would like to know if there's an easier/ more logical way to go about this.

```
wordbank=["green", "blue", "gold", "red", "pink"]

rowswwords = []

with open("input.csv", mode='r') as csv_input: 
    with open("output.csv", 'wb') as csv_output: 
        writer = csv.writer(csv_output)
        for row in csv.reader(csv_input): 
            for word in wordbank:
                if word in row[1]: 
                    writer.writerow(row+[word]) 
                    rowswwords.append(row)
                    break
            if row not in rowswwords:
                writer.writerow(row+[""])
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If your wordbank is big, you probably should loop in your row instead of the bank. And test for each word of your row, if it is in the wordbank.

Comment: this looks pretty much like how I would do it.  Your row is just a string, and you are checking the word is in the string.  Looks pretty logical